# Run-time error '5': Invalid procedure call or argument

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2010

I wrote some code in Microsoft Excel 2010 which is attached to an ActiveX Command Button. The code is suppose to find the last row in a spreadsheet, add the first column to a collection and remove duplicates, create a new spreadsheet for the table of contents and list each unique value from the collection and create a named range to be used with the other spreadsheet as a drop-down list. Although as of yesterday I am now receiving above error in the title. Below is the code:

```
Option Explicit
Private Sub btnCloseShipsList_Click()
'===============================================================================================
'Description: Builds the List Data Validation drop-down menus and hides all sheets except [SITE, _
    SYSTEM or INVESTIGATION REQ'D]
'Originally written by: Troy Pilewski
'Date: 2016-01-20
'===============================================================================================
Dim i As Integer
Dim xWs As Worksheet, xWb As Workbook, rng As Range, ws As Worksheet, wsHull As Worksheet
Dim lngLastRow As Long, lngShipRow, lngLastHull As Long
Dim xTitle As String, strShips() As String
Dim vntShips As Variant, Ships As Collection


'Turn off application events to speed up code
With Application
    .DisplayAlerts = False
    .ScreenUpdating = False
End With

'Assigns a string to the title variable
xTitle = "TABLE OF CONTENTS"

'Unhides TABLE OF CONTENTS sheet and deletes it to recreate a new one
Application.Sheets(xTitle).Visible = xlSheetVisible
Application.Sheets(xTitle).Delete
Application.Sheets.Add Before:=Worksheets(1)

'Sets the Datasheet as the active worksheet
Set xWs = Application.ActiveSheet
Set wsHull = Application.Sheets("HULL_TYPES")

xWs.Name = xTitle

'Creates a title row
With xWs.Cells(1, 1)
    .Value = "Sheet Names"
    .Font.Bold = True
End With
'Creates a generic placeholder
With xWs.Cells(2, 1)
    .Value = "SHIPNAME (CLASS)"
End With

'Determine the last row with values
Set xWs = Application.Sheets("SHIPS")

'Call DeleteEntireRow

'Call SystemNamePropigation

lngLastRow = xWs.Range("A:A").Find( _
    What:="*", _
    After:=xWs.Range("A1"), _
    Lookat:=xlByRows, _
    SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
    SearchDirection:=xlPrevious _
).Row
lngLastHull = wsHull.Range("A:A").Find( _
    What:="*", _
    After:=wsHull.Range("A1"), _
    Lookat:=xlByRows, _
    SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
    SearchDirection:=xlPrevious _
).Row

'Creates and adds each Ship to a collection
If lngLastRow > 2 Then
    vntShips = xWs.Range("A3:A" & lngLastRow).Value
    Set Ships = New Collection

    'Loop through the array of all Ship values (duplicates will be in this list)
    For lngShipRow = LBound(vntShips, 1) To UBound(vntShips, 1)

        'Check the first unique value of a Ship
        If KEYISINCOLLECTION(Ships, CStr(vntShips(lngShipRow, 1))) = False Then

            'Add the first unique Ship to the collection
            Ships.Add CStr(vntShips(lngShipRow, 1)), CStr(vntShips(lngShipRow, 1))
        End If
    Next lngShipRow

    'Converts collection to a string
    With Ships
        ReDim strShips(.Count) As String
    '    MsgBox UBound(strShips)
        For i = 1 To .Count
            strShips(i) = .Item(i)
        Next i
    End With
End If

For Each ShipRecord In xWs.Range("F3:F" & lngLastRow)
    If ShipRecord = vbNullString And Range(ShipRecord.Address).Offset(0, -1) = vbNullString Then
        'MsgBox Range(ShipRecord.Address).Offset(0, -2) & " has No Scan Data"
    ElseIf ShipRecord = vbNullString And Range(ShipRecord.Address).Offset(0, -1) > Now() - 1 Then
        Range(ShipRecord.Address) = "0"
    End If
Next

'Loops through worksheet and lists them in a column and adds a hyperlink to the sheet
Set xWs = Application.Sheets("TABLE OF CONTENTS")

If lngLastRow > 2 Then
    For i = LBound(strShips) + 1 To UBound(strShips)
        With wsHull
            ReDim HullTypes(lngLastHull)
            HullTypes = .Range("A3:B" & lngLastHull).Value
        End With
        With Application.WorksheetFunction
            Dim HullNumber As String
            HullNumber = .Index(HullTypes, .Match(strShips(i), wsHull.Range("A3:A" & lngLastHull)), 2)
        End With
        With xWs.Cells(i + 2, 1)
            .Value = strShips(i) & Chr(32) & "(" & HullNumber & ")"
    '        .Hyperlinks.Add anchor:=Cells(i + 1, 1), Address:="", _
    '        SubAddress:="'" & Worksheets(i).name & "'!$A$1"
        End With
    '    MsgBox Cells(i + 2, 1)
    Next
    'For i = 2 To Worksheets.count - 3
    '    With Cells(i + 1, 1)
    '        .value = Worksheets(i + 3).name
    '        .Hyperlinks.Add anchor:=Cells(i + 1, 1), Address:="", _
    '        SubAddress:="'" & Worksheets(i).name & "'!$A$1"
    '    End With
    'Next
End If

'Sets the Datasheet as the active worksheet
Set xWb = ActiveWorkbook

'Determine the last row with values
Set xWs = Application.Sheets("TABLE OF CONTENTS")
lngLastRow = xWs.Range("A:A").Find( _
    What:="*", _
    After:=xWs.Range("A1"), _
    Lookat:=xlByRows, _
    SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
    SearchDirection:=xlPrevious _
).Row

'Sets the range for the Named Object
Set rng = xWs.Range("$A$1:$A$" & lngLastRow - 1).Offset(1, 0)

'MsgBox CStr(rng)

'Creates a Named Object Range and assignes its range
xWb.Names.Add Name:="SheetList", RefersTo:=rng

'Changes the column width to autofit to the contents of the column
xWs.Cells(1, 1).EntireColumn.AutoFit

'loops through the all worksheets and hides them unless they are SITE, SYSTEM or INVESTIGATION REQ'D
For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
    If ws.Name = "TABLE OF CONTENTS" Then
        ws.Visible = xlSheetVeryHidden
    ElseIf ws.Name = "HULL_TYPES" Then
        ws.Visible = xlSheetVeryHidden
    ElseIf ws.Name = "SYSTEM_LIST" Then
        ws.Visible = xlSheetVeryHidden
    ElseIf ws.Name = "SITE" Then
        ws.Visible = xlSheetVisible
    ElseIf ws.Name = "SYSTEM" Then
        ws.Visible = xlSheetVisible
    ElseIf ws.Name = "INVESTIGATION REQ'D" Then
        ws.Visible = xlSheetVisible
    Else
        ws.Visible = xlSheetHidden
    End If
Next ws

'Application.Sheets(1).Visible = False
End Sub

Public Function KEYISINCOLLECTION(CollTemp As Collection, KeyToCheck As String) As Boolean
'===============================================================================================
'Description: Validates the selection is not already in the collection
'Originally written by: Zack Barresse
'Date: 2014-09-15
'===============================================================================================

    On Error Resume Next
    KEYISINCOLLECTION = CBool(Not IsEmpty(CollTemp(KeyToCheck)))
    On Error GoTo 0
End Function
```

Comment: What's the line with the error?

Comment: The line is the KEYISINCOLLECTION within the public function.

Comment: I think your code is fine as there is no better way to check for the existence of an item in a collection besides handling the error that is thrown when you access an element that does not exist (using `On Error Resume Next` is one way to do that).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might have disabled the error handler by setting "break on all errors".

In the VBA window, go to `Tools` -> `Options` -> `General` -> `Error Trapping` and choose `Break on Unhandled Errors`.

Comment: I think that this may be the reason. Although, I will have to verify in a few hours when I get back on the computer with the workbook.

Answer (score 0):

Your `KEYISINCOLLECTION()` function works for me

you may want to try this little variation of the code

```
Public Function KEYISINCOLLECTION(CollTemp As Collection, KeyToCheck As String) As Boolean
    Dim x As Variant
    On Error Resume Next
    x = CollTemp(KeyToCheck)
    On Error GoTo 0
    KEYISINCOLLECTION = Not IsEmpty(x)
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

For me, it works as it is, there could be only two possible reasons:

1. One thing that I noticed, if you re run the code and you never `set Ships = Nothing` when finished the first time it may cause weird behavior. 

2. As long this condition is met it shouldn't be a problem `If KEYISINCOLLECTION(Ships, CStr(vntShips(lngShipRow, 1))) = False Then` I saw that this came from a range, could it be there is a formula error in that range?

OT: There are a few opportunities I saw, If I may, why do you set a range.value as a collection series instead of a range and then do .value as needed in the code? 2. Why don't you use a dictionary instead of collection? That function "KEYISINCOLLECTION" is already defined as "Exists" in a dictionary. Don't re invent the wheel ;)